# Proof for an explicit formula for the even Euler numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

The EULER numbers $E_n$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, are defined via the TAYLOR
expansion of the hyperbolic secant:

\begin{equation}
    \text{sech}(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{E_n}{n!} x^n =
    \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{E_{2n}}{(2n)!} x^{2n}
\end{equation}

(the odd ones $E_{2n+1}$ being zero due to the hyberbolic secant's being
an even function).
As close cousins of the celebrated BERNOULLI numbers they, too, show up
everywhere in Analysis, Combinatorics and Number Theory, and as for those
there are many explicit finite expressions for them. One of these is

\begin{equation}
    E_{2n} = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{2^{k-1}} \sum_{m=0}^{k-1} (-1)^m
    \binom{2k}{m} (k-m)^{2n}.
\end{equation}

I have been unable to locate a proof. Does somebody have a reference for
such a one?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this formula appears on the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_numbers#As_a_double_sum. The Wiki page cites Wei, Chun-Fu; Qi, Feng (2015). "Several closed expressions for the Euler numbers". Journal of Inequalities and Applications. 219 (2015). https://doi.org/10.1186/s13660-015-0738-9

Answer (score 1):

@Sam Hopkins: The formula there reads

\begin{equation*}
    E_{2n}=\sum_{k=1}^{2n }(-1)^k\frac{1}{2^k}\sum_{\ell=0}^{2k}(-1)^{\ell}\binom{2k}{\ell}(k-\ell)^{2n}
\end{equation*}

which is slightly different from the formula I gave and which is from

```
NIST Handbook of Mathematical Functions (Olver, F.W.J. et al, Eds.) (CUP 2010),
```

where it is formula 24.6.4 on p. 591, given, however, without clear reference. These formulas are easily seen to be the same, since the $k \ge n+1$ produce zeros, and the $m \le k-1$ and the $m \ge k+1$ match.

Wei et al. mention Guo et al. [5], as a source of the formula, which in this way is seen to have appeared earlier in the NIST Handbook and might be as well already quite old. At any rate, if one strips away the cloud of Bell polynomials evoked in the Wei and Guo papers one is
left, for a proof, with the power series calculations

\begin{equation*}
\text{sech}(x)=\frac{1}{\cosh(x)}=\frac{1}{1+2\sinh^2(x/2)}=
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k 2^{k}\sinh^{2k}(x/2)
\end{equation*}

by expanding $\sinh(t)^m=2^{-t}(\exp(t)-\exp(-t))^m$ via the binomial and exponential series.
The Bell polynomial stuff is needed for the general formalism of inverting a power serie $1-g(t)$ with $\text{ord}(g) \ge 1$, but not in this concrete situation.

Comment: Okay, well if you are happy with this conclusion, you can accept your own answer to take the question off the "unanswered" list. (By the way, I think you have a typo in the first equation: $\frac{1}{2k}$ should be $\frac{1}{2^k}$.)

Comment: @Sam Hopkins: Thanks for indicating the typo. By the way, why did you not classified your comment as an Answer? I would have been OK with that, as I am not with your reaction. Intended no offense.

Comment: Often if all I did was something as simple as check the Wikipedia page, I leave the answer in a comment rather than post a formal answer. And no offense taken.

Comment: @Sam Hopkins: To finish things off, I would have preferred  giving a comment over answering my own question, but comments are very restricted in size. Please classify it as clumsiness.